# Configuring php with Apache - where is php.ini supposed to be?

Tags: php, apache

I am trying to configure Apache with php on CENTOS.

- Apache is 2.2.31 built from source
- PHP is  5.6.18 also built from source.

I used the following configure for the php build:

```
./configure --prefix=/apps/php --with-apxs2=/apps/httpd/bin/apxs --with-config-file-path=/apps/httpd/php --with-mysql
```

The make/make install worked, and then I copied the php.ini-development to /apps/httpd/php/php.ini.

The problem I'm having is that when I view the phpinfo.php in a web page, it shows:

```
Configuration File (php.ini) Path   /apps/httpd/php
Loaded Configuration File   (none)
```

Also I think that it's reading (or not reading) a php.ini file from some unknown location because param changes I make in the /apps/httpd/php/php.ini file are not showing, so I've been trying to determine where it's looking for the php.ini file.  I've even run Apache under strace and I see this:

```
stat("/etc/localtime", {st_mode=S_IFREG|0644, st_size=3519, ...}) = 0
stat("/apps/httpd/\342\200\234/apps/httpd/php/php.ini\342\200\235", 0x7fffe0da9b10) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
open("/apps/httpd/\342\200\234/apps/httpd/php/php.ini\342\200\235/php-apache2handler.ini", O_RDONLY) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
open("/apps/httpd/\342\200\234/apps/httpd/php/php.ini\342\200\235/php.ini", O_RDONLY) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
```

I don't understand because it appears that it's looking in paths that have the "\342\200\234"??

Can anyone tell me (a) what is going on and (b) how I might be able to build php or configure it to work correctly with my Apache?

Thanks,
Jim

P.S.  I've seen some older threads about similar problems but don't seem to be the same or the solutions provided didn't seem to work in my case.

Comment: I assume you did restart Apache after changing php.ini?

Comment: See also php_ini_loaded_file() ...

Comment: Have you considered using the redhat/centos build system? It's not that difficult to create and integrate your own package(s). see e.g. http://theurbanpenguin.com/wp/index.php/building-an-rpm-on-centos-6-5/  (it's actually easier than that because you can copy and edit the existing httpd/php build files)

Answer (score 0):

it looks like character encoding problem "\342\200\235" unexpected characters found in this case "͂Ȁȵ" please rewrite all your commands again for build

Comment: @Kkinsey - yes I did restart - also tried a small .php with php_ini_loaded_file() from http://php.net/manual/en/function.php-ini-loaded-file.php, as you suggested, and got "A php.ini file is not loaded ".  

if ($inipath) {
    echo 'Loaded php.ini: ' . $inipath;
} else {
    echo 'A php.ini file is not loaded';
}
?>

Comment: but why the weird characters?  The configure I used was exactly what I posted, i.e., I don't see any unexpected characters?

Comment: some characters not seen in terminal , it depends on terminal locale settings

Comment: GOT IT!!!  I found that in the Apache httpd.conf, and had a strange double-quote character in front of the path in the PHPIniDir directive.  That was the strange characters and also why it wasn't loading php.ini.  So phpinfo.php is now showing the configuration file loaded!!

Answer (score 0):

"\342\200\235" is a byte sequenc in octal notation. It the same as `e2 80 9c` in hexadecimal. And in [utf-8 encoding this stands](http://utf8-chartable.de/unicode-utf8-table.pl?start=8192&number=128) for "LEFT DOUBLE QUOTATION MARK".

Did you
a) open any of the source files in a word processor
or
b) (more likely) copy&pasted a config argument containing a double-quote e.g. from your browser to the console?

Comment: that is possible.  I just re-built, this type re-typing the configure line, but after that when I try run httpd in single process move (-X), it just sits there and does nothing - going to try again.

Comment: I really suggest looking into the centos build system. You "install" the source rpm of the httpd package shipped with your centos version, copy it to another location, modify some values (e.g. the version), do the same for the php package and you're more or less good to go. The advantage is that - unless you made a breaking change - in all likelihood it will behave just like the "original" package; all the tools and manuals still apply (ok, admittingly there's no guarantee for that, but the chances are higher than for the "step by step from scratch" approach ;-))